# Liip imagine - resize - borders

Tags: image, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I have an issue while using liip_imagine bundle with Symfony 4.1
Everything works fine and here is my configuration:

```
liip_imagine:
filter_sets:
    thumb: 
            quality: 75
            filters:
                    thumbnail:
                            size:   [360, 230]
                            mode: inset
                    background:
                            color: '#f8f9fa'
                            size: [370, 240]
                            position: center
    small:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                    thumbnail:
                            size: [400, 240]
                            mode: inset
                    background:
                            color: '#f8f9fa'
                            size: [410, 250]
                            position: center
    medium:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                    thumbnail:
                            size: [640, 400]
                            mode: inset
                    background:
                            color: '#f8f9fa'
                            size: [650, 410]
                            position: center
    large:
            quality: 100
            filters:
                    thumbnail:
                            size: [800, 600]
                            mode: inset
                    background:
                            color: '#f8f9fa'
                            size: [810, 610]
                            position: center
```

The thing is the image is scaling to the desired size but using something which seems to be a background and is not filling the frame as depicted on this page:
[Link](https://www.debout-les-idees.fr/media/cache/large/uploads/5c365fd00c03c837879179.jpeg)

Is someone able to tell me what's wrong here??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you want to say  undesired white background ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to configure your backgroun settings, The default color is white (#fff), so all you need is to set a size depending on your image input:

```
# app/config/config.yml
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:

        # name our filter set "my_background_filter"
        thumb:
            filters:
                quality: 100

                # use and setup the "background" filter
                background:

                    # set the background color to #00ffff
                    color: '#00ffff'

                    # set a size different from the input image
                    size: [1026, 684]

                    # center input image on the newly created background
                    position: center
```

Comment: Thank you man it's working a bit better but images still ain't filling expected filters size (link to the site if you wanna check: https://www.debout-les-idees.fr/article/32 ). In this example i'm using large filter and it should be a 800x600 image...

Comment: Could update your question with the current configuration of Liip, maybe thumbnail size need to have the same size of background

Comment: I see that the image looks great what's the problem ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that great. Please look how the image doesn't fit (i changed it to show a more explicit case).